# Swamp class to bounce in mobile menu

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not able to toggle nav by swapping the class to change the margin. Is it bad practice to target the `nav` element instead of by class? Can `nav` have a class?

I was trying to make it so that if you click the page or a link, then the menu closes.

I changed the `margin: 0 -250px 0 0;` then swapped the class to have `margin: 0 0 0 0;`

Here is my script:

```
$('#menu-icon').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('nav');
    $(this).toggleClass('navclick');
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="minimenu">
    <div class="minim" for="navigation">
        <a class="far fa-user" href="#M"></a>&nbsp;
        <i class="fas fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="mobileT">
            <li><a id="silentp1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="silentp1-2">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a id="silentp1-3">Our Team</a> </li>
            <li><a id="silentp1-4">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a id="silentp1-5">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#M">Login</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:3.2em;
    right:0;
    width:250px;
    height:80%;
    margin:0 -250px 0 0;

    -moz-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    -o-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);

}

navclick {
    position:fixed;
    top:3.2em;
    right:0;
    width:250px;
    height:80%;
    margin:0 0 0 0;

    -moz-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    -o-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

nav ul {
    width:250px;
    height:100vh;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav li {
    margin:0;     
}

nav a {
    color:#fff !important;
    font-size:1em;
    font-family:'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:12px 15px;
    font-weight:300;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid #333;            */
    cursor:pointer !important;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #B8E5FF !important;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9) !important; 
}

.minimenu {width:200px;} 

.minim {
    display:block;
    font-family:'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    background:transparent;
    width:100px;
    height:49px;
    line-height:49px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    line-height:1.1em;
    position:fixed;
    top:6px;
    right:-2px;
    z-index:500;            
    cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use function addClass() or removeClass().

Tag `<nav>` support all global attributes like class, id etc. (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)

For example like this:

```
.navclick{
    position:fixed;
    top:3.2em;
    right:0;
    width:250px;
    height:80%;
    margin:0 0 0 0;

    -moz-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    -o-transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    transition:all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);

}
```

and js

```
$('.menu-icon').click(function() {
   if($("nav").hasClass('navclick')){
       $("nav").removeClass('navclick')
   }else{
      $("nav").addClass('navclick')
   }
});
```

OR

you can use for margin change jquery function animation. See https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: I tried the above, im still doing something backwards

Comment: i changed nav to a div and added nav as a class to it, the menu doesnt slideout on click